# Typings for a hierarchical recursive data structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write typings for nested NoSQL collections. A collection can be a root collection or a sub-collection. A collection contains documents with IDs, the paths to sub-collections contain the IDs of the parent collection's documents.

The path to a collection could be `accounts` or for sub-collections `accounts/acc-1/users`. The path to a document in a sub-collection looks like this, for example `accounts/acc-1/users/usr-1`

The goal is to have a strongly typed class called `Collection` which has methods for generating collection and document paths, where the argument of those methods require the IDs passed as a map.

Is it possible to infer the types (except the type of the ID `Id<>`) from constructor arguments, without manually passing it as a generic to every sub-collection? I've been playing around with it for a few days now and can't get it to work.

```js
declare const t: unique symbol;
export type Id<T> = string & { readonly [t]: T };

type DocumentIds<C extends Collection> = C extends Collection<infer IdType, infer PC, infer IdKey>
    ? { [k in IdKey]: IdType } & (PC extends void ? {} : DocumentIds<PC>)
    : never;

class Collection<IdType extends string = string, PC extends Collection | void = void, IdKey extends string = string> {
   constructor(
      private readonly collectionName: string,
      private readonly idName: IdKey,
      private readonly parent?: Collection
   ) {}

   getCollectionPath(ids: PC extends void ? void : DocumentIds<PC>) {}

   getDocumentPath(ids: { [k in IdKey]: IdType } & (PC extends void ? {} : DocumentIds<PC>)) {}

   parse(path: string): { [k in IdKey]: IdType } & (PC extends void ? {} : DocumentIds<PC>) {
      return null as any;
   }
}

type AccountId = Id<'Account'>;
type UserId = Id<'User'>;

const AccountCollection = new Collection<AccountId>('accounts', 'accountId');

const UserCollection = new Collection<UserId>('users', 'userId', AccountCollection);

// Does not require an argument since it's a root collection
// returns 'accounts'
AccountCollection.getCollectionPath();

// Requires an argument for the document id
// returns 'accounts/acc-1'
AccountCollection.getDocumentPath({
   accountId: 'acc-1' as AccountId,
});

// Requires an argument for the parent collection
// returns 'accounts/acc-1/users'
UserCollection.getCollectionPath({
   accountId: 'acc-1' as AccountId,
});

// Requires an argument for the parent collection and the document itself
// returns 'accounts/acc-1/users/usr-1'
UserCollection.getDocumentPath({
   accountId: 'acc-1' as AccountId,
   userId: 'usr-1' as UserId,
});

// Return type should be {accountId: AccountId, userId: UserId}
// Return value {accountId: 'acc-1', userId: 'usr-1'}
const ids = UserCollection.parse('accounts/acc-1/users/usr-1');
```

What I'm looking for are only the typings and not the implementation.

Comment: There's quite a lot going on in this code; could you make sure this is a [mre] with the least amount of moving parts necessary to demonstrate the core of your problem?  Right now that code has a bunch of errors in it; maybe you could show a version where everything works but you need to specify generic type arguments more than you want?  The whole thing with symbols and so much `foo as AccountId` is probably distracting from the point and not making it.

Comment: Like, if I try to clear away that stuff, I get something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbKE9W) where the typings keep track of the doc ids of the parent collection directly instead of having a circular type.  If that approach helps, I could write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Is this for Cloud Firestore?